# How to deal with hashed js and css in gatling?

Tags: javascript, css, scala, gatling

I am trying to create a scenario that will work every time but I do not know how to deal with the uniquely hashed javascript and CSS. I could not find any answer in the documentation about that.

What I want specifically is the ability to pass a regex into my get but that is not possible since it only takes a string.

```
.get("/dist/precache-manifest.3efd6185a8d8559962673d45aed7ae98.js")
            .headers(headers_0)
```

I expect a way to be able to somehow get the URL with a regex and then use it in my get above. Is there a way to do that in a Gatling scenario.

Comment: Anisa, I would advice to include a Minimal Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) into your question. It will increase the changes to get an answer and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer I do not know where to begin with this. That is why I do not have a minimum example.

Comment: What I am interested in is in getting the url the way the recorder does and using it in my get.

Comment: is there a previous call which returns the desired resource? Can you post an example of that?

Comment: No, actually there is not.

Comment: so how do you know the value of the resource?

Comment: No its uniquely hashed

Answer (score 0):

I found a way but its a hack and it takes a lot of time I am answering this because someone might want to use this way. However this could be considered a bug.

```
        .get("").queryParam("", _ =>regex("""\/dist\/precache-manifest.[A-Za-z0-9]+.js"""))
        .headers(headers_0),
```

Comment: If there is a better way please post it.

Comment: I am interested in a way that is acceptable and professional even an alternative to this problem is welcomed.